# iAd on iOS5 shows white bar

Tags: ios5, iad

I need some pointers.....

My app is free and has iAd implemented in it.  Everything was working fine on OS 4.x.  However, since I migrated my app to iOS5 and am seeing some differences not.

On iOS5 device, I see a white bar instead of iAd initially - even though the view's background is black.  After a minute or so, the iAd will show up and replace the white bar.  Things work for a while, and then the white bar comes back.

On OS 4.x, don't see the white bar but the rest of the functionality is same...i.e. ads show for a while, and then nothing.

1. White bar - is this a 'feature' in iOS5?
2. Are iAds shown for a period of time only?  i.e. not shown all the time?
3. Are there extended periods where the iAds are not shown?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Did you show the banner view in a non-full-screen super view? I've encountered same problem, and it disappears after I made the ad-banner subview of a full-screen view (1024 by 768 on iPad for example)

Comment: Gosh, that was long time ago.  I am using ad-banner subview - for iPhone though, and only in portrait mode.